# build static tablename with part of another cell and use in a formula

Tags: excel

I need in a cell the year for select the right table:

I have this formula in a cell:

```
='August 2014'!D$37
```

And I need somethink like that:

```
='August $B$2'!D$37
```

But i dont know how i can connect the tablename from a static value and a variable part from another cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'August " & $B$2 &"'!" & CELL("address",D$37))
```